# Struts 2 Session TimeOut

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to struts. I am using Struts2. Please any one can tell me how to **automatically redirect the jsp page after Session has Timeout.**

Answer (score 21):

Well You need to create a way to check if the session has expired or not since Browser has no way to find out if the Session has expired or not.
You need to have following steps

Define session time out in your web.xml like.

```
<session-config>  
        <session-timeout>  
            30  
        </session-timeout>  
    </session-config>
```

One of easy way around Struts2 is to create an [Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/interceptors.html) and check Session validity and if session has expired you can redirect user back to your specified jsp page.Here is a quick view of a sample interceptor

### Interceptor

```
public class SessionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
  @Override
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
      Map<String,Object> session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
      if(session.isEmpty())
          return "session"; // session is empty/expired
      return invocation.invoke();
  }
```

Finally you need to tell Stuts2 that you want to use this interceptor by declaring it in struts.xml file

### struts.xml

```
<interceptor name="session" class="myapp.interceptor.SessionInterceptor" />
<interceptor-stack name="sessionExpirayStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="session"/>
   </interceptor-stack>
```

Now all you need to use this stack declaration in your actions

### Action Configuration

```
<action name="myAction" class="myClass">
    <interceptor-ref name="sessionExpirayStack" />
    <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
    <result name="session">sessionexpired.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

alternative you can declare a global result for `*session*` so that use will be redirected to the same page globally.

For way outside Struts2 you have the option to create a [Servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and can place you session check code inside the filter.All you need to impliment `javax.servlet.Filter` interface

### Session Checking Filter

```
public final CheckSession impliments Filter{
    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }
    public void destroy() {
        this.filterConfig = null;
    }
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain  
            chain) {

        // Put your logic here to check session
    }
}
```

For *Auto-redirect* you have to keep on checking the session by some sort of Ajax call

Answer (score 4):

To *automatially* redirect you'd need to make an Ajax request an see if the session still contains a known value. If the session has timed out, it will be invalidated by the container, and something like a `currentUser` object will no longer be in session.

If that object no longer exists, your Ajax call would return either a flag, a redirect URL, etc. and the Ajax `success` method would check for however you signal they need to be redirected, and set the window location to a constant, or to the redirect URL value returned by the Ajax call.