# In Struts2 Interceptors getting exception on an instance variable that is properly get/set in the interceptor

Tags: java, session, struts2, variable-assignment, interceptor

This issues comes up when executing a particular workflow -

1. User is logged in
2. Session expires
3. User tries to do something on the currently page which triggers an AJAX request
4. Since session is expired the ajax request fails
5. I need to display a message to this effect.

Now the problem appears. I have an interceptor which properly catches that the session expires. It also properly identifies that the original request was AJAX. So this means the interceptor needs to respond with a json response (accepted input format to any of my ajax calls).

**Interceptor Code** -

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private InputStream jsonStream;

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    ... // boilerplate init code.
    if (memberId == null 
        && StringUtils.equals("XMLHttpRequest", request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"))) {

        Map<String, Object> responseObject = Maps.newHashMap();
        Set<String> errors = Sets.newHashSet();
        errors.add("Your session has expired. Please refresh page and login.");

        responseObject.put("errors", errors);
        responseObject.put("success", false);

        jsonStream = ResponseUtils.getJSONResponseStream(responseObject);

        return "json";
    }
}


public InputStream getJsonStream() {
    return jsonStream;
}

public void setJsonStream(InputStream jsonStream) {
    this.jsonStream = jsonStream;
}
```

**struts.xml** code -

```
<package name="raisin" namespace="/raisin" extends="secure">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="authentication" class="interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>
    </interceptors>
    <global-results>
      <result name="json" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        <param name="inputName">jsonStream</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
      </result> 
    </global-results>  
    ...
  </package>
```

So when this workflow is executed I get the below exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [jsonStream] in the invocation stack. Check the &lt;param name=&quot;inputName&quot;&gt; tag specified for this action.
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
```

I do not understand how is this possible since I create public get/set methods inthe interceptor for `jsonStream`. Also I put a sysout in `getJsonStream` method. It turns out it is never called.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Umesh is correct, interceptors need to be thread safe. Also, interceptors aren't pushed on the stack like actions are.

Comment: @DaveNewton Noted. But I need some guidance on what to do next. Can you kindly look at my response to Umesh and tell me how to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe you approach is wrong here and you are not using Interceptors the way they should be used.
Interceptors instances are shared among the Actions.For each request a new instance of action will be created by S2 but the Interceptors will be reused, which means Interceptors are stateless and you are trying to set state of request process in the interceptor.

My suggestion is Don't try to store the data related to request processing as its not part of Interceptor role.
Just check the Ajax request response and try to see what result you are getting back, based on that you can show the error message.

**Update**

One of the possible solution to check session timeout handling.This has been discussed in following thread [struts-2-session-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917016/struts-2-session-timeout)

Comment: Good point. I am relatively new to Struts2 and I am trying to follow some of the legacy code logic, which might not be correct. Having said that how should I I go about solving this issue.
1. Should I be checking if the request is ajax int he interceptor?
2. If yes, and if the session has expired, should I just return a special string say "ajax_session_expired". And then look up "ajax_session_expired" in one of my global results & let that return a proper message?

Thanks, again for the help.

Comment: @Chantz: best way is to check for session expiry through ajax and once you know session has expired better redirect user to any predefined page or can show the message on same page based on your requirement.